# discord.js access to existing message and get reaction count

Tags: discord.js

Hope you could help me a bit on this. I'm trying to code a small function but I am sure to miss something quite obvious here... I tried with the help of many previous messages, but most of them are old discord.js version (I'm on V13)

My code goal is : from the ID of a message, i would like to catch the number of reactions of a specific emoji. I must precise that this is on existing message, not on the event of new message arriving or new reaction. It will be triggered by a cron function.
Other precision : The message will be posted & reacted after the bot is online

```
channel = client.get_channel(CHAN_CHALLENGE_ID);
message = await channel.fetch_message(messageID);
MyValue ==  message.reactions.cache.find(reaction => reaction.emoji.name == MyEmoji).count;
```

I get the error code "client.get_channel" is not a function

Thank you very much in advance for your help !!!

Answer (score 0):

##### Get Channel

[Discord.js: GuildChannelManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager)

```js
const channel = guild.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL ID');
```

##### Get Message

[Discord.js: TextChannel: messages](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=messages)

```js
const message = await channel.messages.fetch('MESSAGE ID');
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! that part was so obvious that I was totally out ! 
Now the third one seems to give me more issues... I can't access to the reaction or reaction count...  but they are all there in the structure... 
I tried this code also, but can't get it work... 
```
MyValue = message.reactions.cache.find(reaction => reaction.emoji.key == MyEmoji).value.count;
```

Comment: After fetching the message., you can try `message.reactions.cache.get(r => r.emoji.name == MyEmoji).count`

Comment: Thank you @ThatsLiamS,
I tried but receive a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined" for the code : 
```MyValue = message.reactions.cache.get(r => r.emoji.name == MyEmoji).count;```
MyValue is defined, message as well and of course ...I'm getting crazy with this very little thing ... can't understand the right way :(